# Get children count of a tree node

Tags: rascal

The [docs for Node](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Node/Node.html) only mention following methods:

`Equal`, `GreaterThan`, `GreaterThanOrEqual`, `LessThan`, `LessThanOrEqual`, `NotEqual`, `Slice`, `Subscription`

It does mention how to access child by index using `Subscription`, but how can I find out the count of children node has to iterate over them?

Here is my use case:

```cpp
Exp parsed = parse(#Exp, "2+(4+3)*48");
println("the number of root children is: " + size(parsed));
```

But it yields error, as `size()` seems to only work with a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different answers, different aspects that are better or worse. Here are a few:

```cpp
import ParseTree;

int getChildrenCount1(Tree parsed) {
   return (0 | it + 1 | _ <- parsed.args);
}
```

`getChildrenCount1` iterates over the raw children of a parse tree node. This includes whitespace and comment nodes (`layout`) and keywords (`literals`). You might want to filter for those, or compensate by division.

On the other hand, this seems a bit indirect. We could also just directly ask for the length of the children list:

```cpp
import List;
import ParseTree;

int getChildrenCount2(Tree parsed) {
   return size(parsed.args) / 2 + 1; // here we divide by two assuming every other node is a layout node
}
```

There is also the way of meta-data. Every parse tree node has a declarative description of the production directly there which can be queried and explored:

```cpp
import ParseTree;
import List;

// immediately match on the meta-structure of a parse node:
int getChildrenCount3(appl(Production prod, list[Tree] args)) {
    return size(prod.symbols);
}
```

This length of symbols should be the same as the length of args.

```cpp
// To filter for "meaningful" children in a declarative way:
int getChildrenCount4(appl(prod(_, list[Symbol] symbols, _), list[Tree] args)) {
    return (0 | it + 1 | sort(_) <- symbols);
}
```

The `sort` filters for context-free non-terminals as declared with `syntax` rules. Lexical children would match `lex` and layout and literals with `layouts` and `lit`.

Without all that pattern matching:

```cpp
int getChildrenCount4(Tree tree) {
    return (0 | it + 1 | s <- tree.prod.symbols, isInteresting(s));
}

bool isInteresting(Symbol s) = s is sort || s is lex;
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, this `parsed.args` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem; have a look in the `ParseTree` module in the standard library for a full definition of the parse tree format. It's pretty rich. The same format is also produced if you reify a grammar type: `#Exp.definitions` contains all the rules in the original grammar in the same format as is used in the resulting parse trees.

Comment: Maybe not completely relevant here, but for the general `Node` case, there is also an `arity` function that returns the number of children.

Comment: The issue here would be that there are some children you don't want to count -- those representing layout (e.g., whitespace). That's why I mentioned it may not be relevant for this situation, but it can be helpful in general.

Comment: @MarkHills yes but that would return 2 here since APPL has two

Comment: @JurgenVinju agreed, I just thought it could be useful to add since the original question was about finding the number of children of a node type, it's just the use case is a parse tree instead.

Comment: @MarkHills that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

So far this seems to work, but it is awful:

```js
int getChildrenCount(Tree parsed) {
    int infinity = 1000;
    for (int i <- [0..infinity]) {
        try parsed[i];
        catch: return i;
    }
    return infinity;
}

void main() {
    Exp parsed = parse(#Exp, "132+(4+3)*48");
    println("the number of root children is: ");
    println(getChildrenCount(parsed));
}
```